# Почему в pdcurses отсутствуют функции для работы с широкими символами

Tags: c++, ncurses

Я установил `pdcurses`. Скачал архив, библиотеку скомпилировал командой `mingw32-make -f Makefile WIDE=Y UTF8=Y`

Однако отсутствуют функции для работы с широкими символами, например `mvaddwstr()`. Подключаю библиотеку так `#include <ncursesw/ncurses.h>`

> error: 'mvaddwstr' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'mvaddstr'?

Все остальные функции, не касающиеся широких символов, есть и работают корректно. Использую Windows, IDE Code::Blocks

Comment: ncursesw это не pdcurses, не тот заголовочный файл включаете

Comment: какой тогда необходим? потому что других заголовочных файлов нет, только множество `ncurses/`, `ncursesw/` и `curses.h`

Comment: Нужен заголовочный файл от pdcurses.

Comment: Что делать, если его нет? Смотрел много инструкций по установке этой библиотеки, и везде подключали `curses.h` или `ncurses/`

Comment: Ну вот, ни разу не `ncursesw/`.

Comment: Где тогда взять заголовочный файл от pdcurses? Не могу нигде найти информацию об этом

Comment: Ну вы же скачали архив с библиотекой - в нем должен был быть нужный заголовочный файл. ¿Как вы вообще что-то включаете, если не знаете, где лежат заголовочные файлы библиотеки?